# Ggplot2 facet_grid repeats y-axis breaks on small scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot2 facet_grid that repeats labels on the y-axis when the sample size is small. On the first plot I want the scale to only show 0 and 1 once at the bottom and top. Ideally the solution would fix this in a dynamic fashion given some argument. If I need to hard code the breaks I can do that, but I haven't been able to find a way to hard code breaks for individual plots. Thanks for your help!

```
g6 <- ggplot(g6_data, aes(x=HOURS, fill=VARIABLE))
g6 <- g6 + facet_grid(VARIABLE ~ ., scales="free_y")
g6 <- g6 + geom_histogram(binwidth=1, color="black", boundary=1)
g6 <- g6 + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-48, 72), label=comma, breaks=seq(-48, 72, by=12))
g6 <- g6 + scale_y_continuous(label=comma)
g6 <- g6 + theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="none")
g6 <- g6 + geom_vline(xintercept=0, size=1)
```

[image]

Attempt to hard code by adding scale_y_continuous breaks results in smear on large sample size:

```
g6 <- ggplot(g6_data, aes(x=HOURS, fill=VARIABLE))
g6 <- g6 + facet_grid(VARIABLE ~ ., scales="free_y")
g6 <- g6 + geom_histogram(binwidth=1, color="black", boundary=1)
g6 <- g6 + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-48, 72), label=comma, breaks=seq(-48, 72, by=12))
g6 <- g6 + scale_y_continuous(label=comma, breaks=seq(0, 400, by=1)
g6 <- g6 + theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="none")
g6 <- g6 + geom_vline(xintercept=0, size=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to fix your problem, let me propose that the thing that you're plotting is not the actual thing you want to plot.

To me, it seems that you are trying to compare distributions between samples/variables. To do this in a visually appealing way, you let the y-axis be free between variables. As you show, this leads to a mess of y-axes labels that are neither appealing nor easy to interpret properly.

My proposal is that you probably want to compare the fractions of observations within a variable in a a particular bin, not the absolute counts. To do this, you can set the y-value of the histogram to `stat(density)` which is the histogram rescaled such that the integral is 1 (i.e. each bin represents a fraction). When doing this, we can set our worry about y-axes aside altogether.

See example below for histograms for different numbers of observations.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200),
                 panel = rep(c(1, 2), c(180, 20)))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density))) +
  facet_grid(panel ~ .)
```

[image]